# Иерархия классов для представления геометрических фигур

Tags: delphi

Всем привет.

На данном этапе просто хочу убедиться, что наследование реализовано корректно. Но когда пробую вызвать GetName, то возвращается только geometry. Остальные значения - пустые. Подорзреваю, что это из-за того, что неправильно работают конструкторы.
Как это исправить?

Т.е., я хочу добиться того, чтобы на данном этапе программа выдавала

geometry
polyline
polygon
ellipse
rectangle
а не только geometry (а затем 4 пустые строки).

Условие задачи
Разработать иерархию классов для представления геометрических 
фигур: прямая, ломанная, прямоугольник, эллипс, многоугольник. 
Разработать контейнер для хранения фигур. 
Контейнер для хранения фигур реализовать в виде интерфейса с 
общими методами для всех фигур. Классы каждой из фигур должны быть 
реализацией данного интерфейса.

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type

  // Описание интерфейса

  //

  // Класс геометрии  - общий класс всей иерархии

  TGeometry = class(TInterfacedObject)

    FName: String;    // поля
    //Length: Real;

    function GetName: String; virtual;  // методы

    procedure SetName(N: String); virtual;

    constructor Create(N: String);

    procedure SetXY;

  end;

  procedure TGeometry.SetXY;
  begin
  end;

  constructor TGeometry.Create(N: String);
  begin
    FName := N;
  end;

  function TGeometry.GetName: String;
  begin
      GetName := FName;
  end;

  procedure TGeometry.SetName(N: String);
  begin
     FName := N;
  end;

  // класс полилинии

  type TPolyline = class(TGeometry)

    XCoords: Array[1..4] of Integer;
    YCoords: Array[1..4] of Integer;
    Length: Real;

    constructor Create(N: String);

    procedure SetXY(x1:Integer; y1:Integer; x2: Integer; y2: Integer; x3: Integer; y3: Integer; x4: Integer; y4: Integer);
    function GetLength: Real;

    function GetName: String; override;
    procedure SetName(N: String); override;

  end;

  constructor TPolyline.Create(N: String);
  var
  i: Integer;
  begin
    inherited Create(N);
    Length := 0;

    for i := 1 to 4 do
    begin
     XCoords[i] := 0;
     YCoords[i] := 0;
    end;
  end;

  procedure TPolyline.SetXY(x1:Integer; y1:Integer; x2: Integer; y2: Integer; x3: Integer; y3: Integer; x4: Integer; y4: Integer);
  begin

    XCoords[1] :=   x1;
    XCoords[2] :=   x2;
    XCoords[3] :=   x3;
    XCoords[4] :=   x4;

    YCoords[1] :=   y1;
    YCoords[2] :=   y2;
    YCoords[3] :=   y3;
    YCoords[4] :=   y4;

  end;

  function TPolyline.GetLength: Real;
  var l: Real;
  begin
    l := Sqrt(  Exp(2*(XCoords[2] - XCoords[1])) + Exp(2*(YCoords[2] - YCoords[1])) +
                Exp(2*(XCoords[3] - XCoords[2])) + Exp(2*(YCoords[3] - YCoords[2])) +
                Exp(2*(XCoords[4] - XCoords[3])) + Exp(2*(YCoords[4] - YCoords[3])) );

    Length := l;
    GetLength := l;

  end;

  procedure TPolyline.SetName(N: String);
  begin
   inherited SetName(N);
  end;

  function TPolyline.GetName: String;
  begin
    inherited GetName;
  end;

  // класс линии

  type TLine = class(TPolyline)

    constructor Create(N: String);

    procedure SetXY(x1:Integer; y1:Integer; x2: Integer; y2: Integer);
    function  GetLength:Real;

    function GetName: String; override;
    procedure SetName(N: String); override;

  end;

  constructor TLine.Create(N:String);
  begin

    XCoords[1] :=   0;
    XCoords[2] :=   0;

    YCoords[1] :=   0;
    YCoords[2] :=   0;

  end;
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  function TLine.GetName:String;
  begin
   inherited GetName;
  end;

  procedure TLine.SetName(N:String);
  begin
   inherited SetName(N);
  end;
 ////////////////////////////////////////

  procedure TLine.SetXY(x1:Integer; y1:Integer; x2: Integer; y2: Integer);
  begin

     XCoords[1] :=   x1;
     XCoords[2] :=   x2;

     YCoords[1] :=   y1;
     YCoords[2] :=   y2;

  end;

  function TLine.GetLength:Real;
  var
  l: Real;
  begin

   l :=  Sqrt(  Exp(2*(XCoords[2] - XCoords[1])) + Exp(2*(YCoords[2] - YCoords[1]))  );
   Length := l;

   GetLength := l;
  end;

  // класс полигона

  type TPolygon = class(TGeometry)

    XCoords: Array[1..5] of Integer;
    YCoords: Array[1..5] of Integer;

    function GetArea: Real;

    function GetName: String; override;
    procedure SetName(N: String); override;

    procedure SetXY(x1:Integer; y1:Integer; x2: Integer; y2: Integer; x3: Integer; y3: Integer;
                    x4:Integer; y4:Integer; x5: Integer; y5: Integer);

    constructor Create(N: String);

  end;

  function TPolygon.GetArea: Real;
  begin
    GetArea := 0;
  end;

  function TPolygon.GetName: String;
  begin
    inherited GetName;
  end;

  procedure TPolygon.SetName(N:String);
  begin
     inherited SetName(N);
  end;

  procedure TPolygon.SetXY(x1:Integer; y1:Integer; x2: Integer; y2: Integer; x3: Integer; y3: Integer;
                    x4:Integer; y4:Integer; x5: Integer; y5: Integer);
  begin

    XCoords[1] :=   x1;
    XCoords[2] :=   x2;
    XCoords[3] :=   x3;
    XCoords[4] :=   x4;
    XCoords[5] :=   x5;

    YCoords[1] :=   y1;
    YCoords[2] :=   y2;
    YCoords[3] :=   y3;
    YCoords[4] :=   y4;
    YCoords[5] :=   y5;

  end;

  constructor TPolygon.Create(N: String);
  begin

    inherited Create(N);

    XCoords[1] :=   0;
    XCoords[2] :=   0;
    XCoords[3] :=   0;
    XCoords[4] :=   0;
    XCoords[5] :=   0;

    YCoords[1] :=   0;
    YCoords[2] :=   0;
    YCoords[3] :=   0;
    YCoords[4] :=   0;
    YCoords[5] :=   0;

  end;

  // класс эллипса

  type TEllipse = class(TPolygon)

    //XCoords: Array[1..4] of Integer;
    //YCoords: Array[1..4] of Integer;

    function GetArea: Real;

    function GetName: String;  override;
    procedure SetName(N: String);   override;

    procedure SetXY(x1:Integer; y1:Integer; x2: Integer; y2: Integer; x3: Integer; y3: Integer;
                    x4:Integer; y4:Integer);

    constructor Create(N: String);

  end;

  constructor TEllipse.Create(N: String);
  begin

    inherited Create(N);

    XCoords[1] :=   0;
    XCoords[2] :=   0;
    XCoords[3] :=   0;
    XCoords[4] :=   0;

    YCoords[1] :=   0;
    YCoords[2] :=   0;
    YCoords[3] :=   0;
    YCoords[4] :=   0;

  end;

  function TEllipse.GetArea: Real;
  begin
   GetArea := 1;
  end;

  function TEllipse.GetName: String;
  begin
    inherited GetName;
  end;

  procedure TEllipse.SetName(N:String);
  begin
     inherited SetName(N);
  end;

  procedure TEllipse.SetXY(x1:Integer; y1:Integer; x2: Integer; y2: Integer; x3: Integer; y3: Integer;
                    x4:Integer; y4:Integer);
  begin

    XCoords[1] :=   x1;
    XCoords[2] :=   x2;
    XCoords[3] :=   x3;
    XCoords[4] :=   x4;

    YCoords[1] :=   y1;
    YCoords[2] :=   y2;
    YCoords[3] :=   y3;
    YCoords[4] :=   y4;

  end;

  // класс прямоугольника

  type TRectangle = class(TPolygon)

    //XCoords: Array[1..4] of Integer;
    //YCoords: Array[1..4] of Integer;

    function GetArea: Real;

    function GetName: String; override;
    procedure SetName(N: String); override;

    procedure SetXY(x1:Integer; y1:Integer; x2: Integer; y2: Integer; x3: Integer; y3: Integer;
                    x4:Integer; y4:Integer);

    constructor Create(N: String);

  end;

  constructor TRectangle.Create(N: String);
  begin

    inherited Create(N);

    XCoords[1] :=   0;
    XCoords[2] :=   0;
    XCoords[3] :=   0;
    XCoords[4] :=   0;

    YCoords[1] :=   0;
    YCoords[2] :=   0;
    YCoords[3] :=   0;
    YCoords[4] :=   0;

  end;

  procedure TRectangle.SetXY(x1:Integer; y1:Integer; x2: Integer; y2: Integer; x3: Integer; y3: Integer;
                    x4:Integer; y4:Integer);
  begin

    XCoords[1] :=   x1;
    XCoords[2] :=   x2;
    XCoords[3] :=   x3;
    XCoords[4] :=   x4;

    YCoords[1] :=   y1;
    YCoords[2] :=   y2;
    YCoords[3] :=   y3;
    YCoords[4] :=   y4;

  end;

  function TRectangle.GetName: String;
  begin
    inherited GetName;
  end;

  procedure TRectangle.SetName(N:String);
  begin
     inherited SetName(N);
  end;

  function TRectangle.GetArea: Real;
  var
  A: Real;
  begin
    A := (XCoords[4] - XCoords[1]) * (YCoords[2] - YCoords[1]);
    GetArea := A;
  end;

var

geom, polyline, polygon, line, ellipse, rectangle: TGeometry;

n: String;
a: Integer;

begin

geom := TGeometry.Create('geometry');
n := geom.GetName;
WriteLn(n);

//polyline
polyline := TPolyline.Create('polyline');
n := polyline.GetName;
WriteLn(n);
//polygon
polygon := TPolyline.Create('polygon');
n := polygon.GetName;
WriteLn(n);
//ellipse
ellipse := TEllipse.Create('ellipse');
n := ellipse.GetName;
WriteLn(n);
//rectangle
rectangle := TRectangle.Create('rectangle');
n := rectangle.GetName;
WriteLn(n);

ReadLn;

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Что касается "чтобы на данном этапе программа выдавала". Уберите в потомках `GetName` (в потомках он у вас ничего не возвращает из-за этого у вас и пусто выводится) и `SetName`. Они у вас уже реализованы в `TGeometry`.

Что касается самого задания, то не совсем понятно как может быть один интерфейс, скажем, для линии и эллипса. Интерфейсов должно быть много и каждый из классов в вашей иерархии может реализовать один или несколько интерфейсов. Все зависит как вы эти интерфейсы себе представляете. Про интерфейсы гуглите... Вот например [раз](http://www.prestwood.com/ASPSuite/KB/Document_View.asp?QID=101439), [два](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Interface)....

В принципе можно себе представить один такой интерфейс, но работать с ним будет жутко неудобно. Типа реализации универсального геттера, сеттера, в которых будут мега case'ы что возвращать в зависимости от запрошенного свойства. например `obj.getProp('Length');` или `obj.setProp('x',10);` бррр.

Кроме того, у вас неверная структура и класса и модуля.

- Создайте секции в классах `private`, `protected` и `public` (если не знаете что они означают ознакомьтесь в документации), разнесите методы и поля в соответствующие секции.
- Создайте свойства, в частности `Name` с соответствующими сеттером и геттером (они у вас уже есть, а свойства нет, неаккуратно).
- Не наследуйте методы базовых классов без необходимости. Ваши `GetName` и `SetName` сломали реализованный механизм в родителе. Вы вообще должны забыть про эти методы в потомках: "работает - не трогай".
- Эллипс не должен быть потомком ломанной. Типа "собака - это тоже машина, ведь четыре колеса можно заменить на четыре ноги и узнать в итоге какой крутящий момент у бульдога в максимальной комплектации".
- По поводу модуля. Вынесите свою иерархию в отдельный `unit`, разнесите корректно `interface` (определение классов) и реализацию (`implementation`). Не стоит всю простыню пихать в один модуль, это неудобно и небезопасно (опять читать про `private` секции).
- Ну и по мелочи там еще... бывают ломанные, состоящие из 7 точек и даже из 10 :)

ЗЫ Для начала реализация нормальная, но до релиза надо что-то больше, чем один видео урок...